# Why is my code giving me the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver error in my web application?

Tags: java, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I've built a dynamic web project that asks for a client's basic information in a .jsp file. This information is then processed by a servlet and passed to a DAO so I can store the data in mssql. When the method `addHost()` is called on the DAO, I'm getting the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` error.

I thought that there was a problem with my driver so I tried running the code, in the same project, but just as a regular java application using `main(String[] args)`. It worked perfectly, so I'm having trouble understanding why this code isn't working through a web application.

Can somebody explain to me why I'm getting this error only when I run the method through a web application?

```
public void addHost(Host userHost) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Hosts;integratedSecurity=true;";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        try {
            String query = "insert into HostsInfo values(?,?,?,?,?);";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, userHost.getName());
            pstmt.setString(2, userHost.getEmail());
            pstmt.setString(3, userHost.getPword());
            pstmt.setString(4, userHost.getCity());
            pstmt.setInt(5, userHost.getGuestCount());          
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver is part of somejar. It must be available in the classpath when deployed application runs.  Please add more details about deployments environment. (how was it built, how was it running)

Comment: do you have the jar file for the sql driver in your `web/WEB-INF/lib`?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using JDBC outside of an application server, the DriverManager class manages the establishment of connections. Specify to the DriverManager which JDBC drivers to try to make Connections with. The easiest way to do this is to use Class.forName() on the class that implements the java.sql.Driver interface. With MySQL Connector, the name of this class is <>. With this method, you could use an external configuration file to supply the driver class name and driver parameters to use when connecting to a database.

You can do something like this:

```
public class LoadDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

After the driver has been registered with the DriverManager, you can obtain a Connection instance that is connected to a particular database by calling DriverManager.getConnection().

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the driver in my `web/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Once I also placed the driver (`mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8`) in the `web/WEB-INF/lib` folder the code worked great with no run-time error and transferred the data smoothly to the database.

Apparently, for web applications, including the driver only in the classpath isn't enough. It also needs to be included in the `web/WEB-INF/lib` folder.